# Try hard to learn PowerShell error "The hash literal was incomplete."

Tags: powershell, syntax-error

```
Get-Process s* |
    where {s$_.Path} |
    dir |
    sort LastWriteTime |
    Format-Table fullname, name,@{label="LastWriteTime";Expr={$_.LastWriteTime}
```

Error:

```
The hash literal was incomplete.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncompleteHashLiteral
```

Could You please give me a hint how to rewrite, please?

Comment: how many open curly braces do you have and how many closing?

Comment: Your calculated property is missing a closing curly bracket: `@{label="...";Expr={...}` -> `@{label="...";Expr={...}}`

Comment: The term `'s$_.Path'` is not recognized…

Comment: If you used something like the [Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment (ISE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/windows-powershell-integrated-scripting-environment--ise-?view=powershell-6) it would give you hints about missing }s and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a curly brace. But there's more problems in your code.
It is not possible to pipe a System.Diagnostics.Process object to 'dir'

I made this, which I think gives the output you want:

```
Get-Process s* |where {$_.Path} | ForEach-Object {Get-Item $_.Path } |
Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Format-Table fullname, name,LastWriteTime
```

What it does:

- Get all processes where the name start with an s and the returned object has the Path property defined
- Get the file object of each process
- sort the file objects by LastWriteTime
- Format the output

Comment: If it is not possible to pipe a System.Diagnostics.Process object to 'dir', how does it nevertheless work?

Comment: @AndrewMorton In my code the process object(s) are piped to Foreach-Object that gets a file object foreach process that is passed by invoking Get-Item, using the path property of the process object.

Comment: I tried your code and the OP's corrected code, and both gave me the same output (PS version 5.1). I was wondering why the OP's code works with `dir`.

Comment: Thank You very much, indeed i missed  } and added unfortunately {s$_.Path}

Comment: I didn't even test the code piping to dir :-) It was clear to me that wouldn't work. I was wrong. I see it works. Wow! The explanation here is, to me, an almost incredible flexibility of the dir (Get-ChildItem) cmdlet